# JDBC Connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
  package dbconn;

  import java.sql.*;

   public class DBConn {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_prac";
            String userName = null;
            String passCode = null;

           Connection conn = null;
           ResultSet resultSet = null;
          Statement statement = null;

        try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, userName, passCode);

        } catch(Exception e) {
           System.err.print("Error");
         }
        }
       }
```

I've been trying to connect jdbc with mysql but I'm constantly unsuccessful. I'm getting error at runtime at forName() and getConnection() methods. I am absolutely blank what is wrong, where am I going wrong. This is my code which is creating problems. But when copying and pasting someone else program into my IDE(Eclipse And Netbeans both) it gives error at runtime too.[Below is the image of the libraries with I've added. I am tired of searching the results on google. help is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBenb.png)

Comment: Sir kindly forward me the link of that question over here. I'll be thankful of yours

Comment: The link is at the top.